# Div positioning (y-axis) is the same as previous div y-axis position, unwanted behavior

Tags: html, css

So i have this array that represents a math formula. For equation a / b, Structure is

```
[[a],/,[b]]
```

I've got it working on react and can display the values correctly, problem is the positioning of the last div, that takes the y-axis of the previous div. Expected result:

```
 ________________
| |     a      | |
|1|------------|2|
| |     b      | |
------------------
```

the creation of the divs goes: div1, div a, middle line, div b, div 2. Div 2 is behaving in a way that takes the y-axis (top position) of div b. Here is what i got:[image]
As you can see highlighted the top position of div 2 is at the middle of the container, i want something that can automatically place the div at the top if theres no more space on a "column". Keep in mind this is supposed to be variable and the equation array can change. I've basically tried placing display inline, inline-block, block and others to no avail, plus float left, and even float left + right on the last one and still no luck. Codepen trying to replicate my problem: https://codepen.io/dariovillalta/pen/yLLrgEw

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example reproducing your issue.

Comment: my bad Awais. https://codepen.io/dariovillalta/pen/yLLrgEw. Not exactly as my project but you can see the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS grid layout:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.app {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5% 90% 5%;
  grid-template-rows: 49% 2% 49%;
  text-align: center;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #F9D342;
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
}
.highlight.left {
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
}
.highlight.right {
  grid-column: 3 / span 1;
}

.middleSection {
  background-color: #bbdefb;
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
}
.middleSection.top {
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
}
.middleSection.bottom {
  grid-row: 3 / span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="highlight left">
    \
  </div>
  <div class="middleSection top">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="divisionSign">
  </div>
  <div class="middleSection bottom">
    b
  </div>
  <div class="highlight right">
    \
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```css
.app {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #F9D342;
  width: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.highlight.last {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.middleSection {
  width: 90%;
  height: 49%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #bbdefb;
  float: left;
}

.divisionSign {
    width: 90%;
    height: 2%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="highlight">
    \
  </div>
  <div class="middleSection">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="divisionSign">
  </div>
  <div class="middleSection">
    b
  </div>
  <div class="highlight last">
    \
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i was looking for a more flexible solution, but thanks! if no one else answers, i'll accept this answer.

Comment: I did that using CSS grid in another answer, see if that's flexible.